# IMAP outlook email imap_search returns only 1 data using PHP

Tags: php, imap

Hi I have this IMAP imap_search connection my problem is the return data from imap_search throws only one data but the result of the imap_search returns an array. But when I do foreach on it. It throws only 1 data. here is my connection

```
 $connection = imap_open('{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'sample@email.com, 'password') or die('Cannot connect to Outlook: ' . imap_last_error());
```

my imap_search

```
$emailDataSendThisFile = imap_search($connection, 'FROM "@wecode-x.com"');
```

when I do

```
print_r($emailDataSendThisFile);
```

this is the return result

```
Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 466 [2] => 467 [3] => 468 [4] => 469 )
```

which has 5 data. but when I do foreach on that it returns only one data.
Can someone help me figured this thing out? Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA

Comment: Provide code with `foreach` usage.

Comment: thank you guys! i already solve it